# Gujarati Fonts not Rendering Correctly

Tags: luatex, rendering, indic

On my old computer the output of my LaTeX file with the Gujarati fonts was very nice. But now on the new Laptop (Windows 10, MikTeX 2.9, WinEdt Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit) the output has changed. Earlier also I was having the same set of programs (Windows 10, MikTeX 2.9, WinEdt Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit). The MWE is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} %for gujarati fonts in Dedication

\setmainfont{shruti}[Script=Gujarati, Renderer=Harfbuzz]
%add Renderer = Harfbuzz




\begin{document}

  ગુજરાતના પહેલા મુખ્યમંત્રી કોણ હતા?
\end{document}
```

I set LuaLaTex on the panel and then by pressing F9 Function Key compile the code. The out put [image: This is the output]

Comment: Add `Ligatures=TeX`. For some reason ligatures are disabled by default.

Comment: @JairoADelRio Thanks but it gives the same output.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you should update your distribution.

Comment: you quite clearly don't use the harfbuzz renderer. This means that your tex system is not up-to-date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I checked miktex-harfbuzz-bin-x64-2.9 is Packaged and installed on 6 Feb 2020. However, there are 433 packages needed to be updated. I am updating and then will revert back. By the way is my following code correct? Is my compilation method correct? Please help. 

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} %for gujarati fonts in Dedication

\setmainfont[Script=Gujarati,Ligatures=TeX, Renderer = Harfbuzz]{shruti}


\begin{document}

  ગુજરાતના પહેલા મુખ્યમંત્રી કોણ હતા?
\end{document}

Comment: Thanks everyone. I updated the system and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was fixed by updating the TeX distribution.

Comment: I do not know how to vote for closing it. But yes, it has been fully resolved with the help of active helpful members. Thanks everyone.